# My Admob Ad Covering App Content in Tab Fragment - How to Fix

Tags: android-layout, admob, android-relativelayout

I want to know how to place admob ad in bottom of screen which don't cover any part of app content as Im using RelativeLayout in xml. Please help me to fix this issue as quick as possible thanks.

**activity_main.xml**

`

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-0000000000000/00000000000">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

```
     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-00000000000000/00000000000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add adView inside your relative layout and then **add android:layout_below property**

Comment: Hi Amod, i Don't understand your answer. Could you please explain it again easily

Comment: @SaeedRehman add layout_below property in your adview. see above for example

Comment: @ Amod Gokhale when I add that property it won't show ad when open app

Comment: YES bro it works but ads show on center of screen how to show it bottom.thanks

Comment: add this to your AdView android:gravity="bottom"

Comment: Thanks bro finally i fixed it